# javascript var statement per scope

Tags: javascript

Looks like a lot of var per  scope is a waste of bytes and bad code habits. I dont know how to fix my code. how should I edit the lines below as per good JS practices?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
    var jump_page = '{LA_JUMP_PAGE}:';
    var on_page = '{ON_PAGE}';
    var per_page = '{PER_PAGE}';
    var base_url = '{A_BASE_URL}';
    var style_cookie = 'style';
    var style_cookie_settings = '{A_COOKIE_SETTINGS}';
    var onload_functions = new Array();
    var onunload_functions = new Array();

    /**
    * Find a member
    */
    function find_username(url)
    {
        popup(url, 760, 570, '_usersearch');
        return false;
    }

    /**
    * New function for handling multiple calls to window.onload and window.unload by pentapenguin
    */
    window.onload = function()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < onload_functions.length; i++)
        {
            eval(onload_functions[i]);
        }
    };

    window.onunload = function()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < onunload_functions.length; i++)
        {
            eval(onunload_functions[i]);
        }
    };

// ]]>
</script>
```

Comment: If you're looking for someone to review your code you should post this on [codereview.se]

Comment: Why do you think multiple var declarations are bad? Its perfectly fine, IMO.

Comment: As for real bad code prectices, I'd watch out for that `new Array` instead of `[]` and all those uses of eval.

Comment: all I know is that jslints trows out so many errors for this code.

Answer (score 0):

I always recommend scoping variables to only the scope that needs them. It's a common error source to use global variables since you can have conflicts.

I will some times wrap my code in JavaScript closures to avoid adding variables to the global scope since variables in global scope never become eligible for garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to avoid polluting the global `window` scope then you can wrap the whole thing up like this:

```
(function() {
  "use strict";
  var onunload_functions = [];

  window.onunload = function()
  {
    for (var i = 0; i < onunload_functions.length; i++)
    {
      eval(onunload_functions[i]);
    }
  };

}());
```

This closure will prevent random `var` variables being added to window / global scope.